# Automatically link form and user using OneToOneField

Tags: python, django

I have create a model form using also OneToOneField field to link it to my user, my problem is that I have to go to the admin section to manually select the user to make it works. Is it possible to have the user linked to the form submitted automatically?
Also this may be stupid but when I use user.userinformation.gender to get the info about gender I get back "m", is there a way to access the label "Male" instead? TThank for yours help!
My code:

```
models.py

class UserInformation(models.Model): 
   gender_choice = [('m', 'Male'),('f', 'Female')]  

   user = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=True,  null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)   
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
   gender = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=gender_choice)    
   phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
   email = models.EmailField()
```

```
forms.py

class UserInformationForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = UserInformation
       fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'gender', 'phone', 'email',)
```

```
views.py 
def add_information(request):
   if request.method == "POST":
       form = UserInformationForm(request.POST)        
       if form.is_valid():          
           form.save()
           messages.success(request, 'Form submitted')         
   else:
       form = UserInformationForm()
   return render(request, 'accounts/profile/add_information.html', {'form': form})

def show_profile(request):
   profile_info = UserInformation.objects.all()

   return render(request, 'accounts/profile/user_profile.html', {'profile_info': profile_info})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can link the `.user` of the `UserInformation` to the logged in user with:

```
from django.shorcuts import redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def add_information(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
       form = UserInformationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
       if form.is_valid():          
           form.instance.user = request.user
           form.save()
           messages.success(request, 'Form submitted')
           return redirect('name-of-some-view')
   else:
       form = UserInformationForm()
   return render(request, 'accounts/profile/add_information.html', {'form': form})
```

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are looking for is the `initial` attribute of `UserInformationForm` instance but you need to add `user` to the form fields.

```
form = UserInformationForm(initial={"user":request.user.id})
```

If you dont want your user to see/edit the information, consider using a `HiddenInput` widget in your `ModelForm` or set disabled attribute.

```
class UserInformationForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = UserInformation
       fields = '__all__'
       widgets = {'user': forms.HiddenInput()}
```